# How to remove the web address from graph in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

I am creating a graph in HTML. I am using the API amCharts, but the problem is that it shows the text "amchart" within the graph.

How can I remove that text so that it may look OK?

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    var chartData = [{
      country: "USA",
      visits: 400,
      color: "#FF0F00"
    }, {
      country: "China",
      visits: 380,
      color: "#FF6600"
    }, {
      country: "Japan",
      visits: 360,
      color: "#FF9E01"
    }, {
      country: "Germany",
      visits: 340,
      color: "#FCD202"
    }, {
      country: "UK",
      visits: 320,
      color: "#F8FF01"
    }, {
      country: "France",
      visits: 300,
      color: "#B0DE09"
    }, {
      country: "India",
      visits: 240,
      color: "#04D215"
    }, {
      country: "Spain",
      visits: 200,
      color: "#0D8ECF"
    }, {
      country: "Netherlands",
      visits: 140,
      color: "#0D52D1"
    }, {
      country: "Russia",
      visits: 100,
      color: "#2A0CD0"
    }, {
      country: "South Korea",
      visits: 80,
      color: "#8A0CCF"
    }, {
      country: "Canada",
      visits: 20,
      color: "#CD0D74"
    }];
    AmCharts.ready(function () {
      chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
      chart.dataProvider = chartData;
      chart.categoryField = "country";
      chart.startDuration = 1;
      // AXES
      // category
      var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
      categoryAxis.labelRotation = 45; // this line makes category values to be rotated
      categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
      categoryAxis.fillAlpha = 1;
      categoryAxis.fillColor = "#FAFAFA";
      categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
      // value
      var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
      valueAxis.dashLength = 5;
      valueAxis.title = "Visitors from country"
      valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
      chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
      // GRAPH
      var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
      graph.valueField = "visits";
      graph.colorField = "color";
      graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]";
      graph.type = "column";
      graph.lineAlpha = 0;
      graph.fillAlphas = 1;
      chart.addGraph(graph);
      // WRITE
      chart.write("chartdiv");
    });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @houstongolden doing this is illegal without purchasing licence.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the [product website](http://www.amcharts.com/download) :

> You can download and use all amCharts products for free. The only limitation of the free version is that a small link to this web site will be displayed in the top left corner of your charts. If you would like to use charts without this link, or you appreciate the software and would like to support its creators, please purchase a commercial license.

So you need to purchase a commercial license ...

Comment: Thanks  is there any other free which we can use can you please tell me if you have any idea

Comment: @user1520252 There are a lot of open source JavaScript charts packages out there .. [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) to name a few ...

Comment: @ManseUK thanks for pointing it out, it's already free and requires only a tiny miny copyright and people still abuse it :\ if you guys buy it you'll even get priority support and you'll support the developers - think about it ;)

Comment: I modified the code.Now am not getting the "Chart by amchart.js".Can i use this is in public domains.Please suggest me.

Comment: or else i use the same plugin and once document is ready can i find the element and remove from my code..

Comment: @Gauti your breaking the license of the product - if you want to use it commercially with the message removed then purchase the product

Comment: @user2587222 This should not be used in public domain. Removing it without purchasing licence is illegal.