# Replace some text in html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amcharts

I want to replace some kind of text occurrence in my html with some other text.
Actually I just want to remove chart ad that comes with free version of amcharts and I am wondering if there is a way to do it with jQuery?

The tag which contains this is:

```
<tspan y="6" x="0">chart by amcharts.com</tspan>
```

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can download and use all amCharts products for free. The only limitation of the free version is that a small link to this web site will be displayed in the top left corner of your charts. If you would like to use charts without this link, or you appreciate the software and would like to support its creators, please purchase a commercial license.

So you need to purchase a commercial license.                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448925/how-to-remove-the-web-address-from-graph-in-html

Comment: I know but just for educational purposes how can i remove that link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to do something like this:

```
$("tspan").each(function(){
    if($(this).text()=='chart by amcharts.com'){
        $(this).text('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of removing it, please hide it using this

```
$("tspan").css('display','none');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){
        $('tspan ').html('');
        });
```